# Magento 2 custom dashboard Page

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect, admin-controller, dashboard

I want to show a completely custom dashboard. I have a controller for that. I just want to show this page when Admin login. I don't want to show the default Magento dashboard controller I want my controller to be a default one.

Comment: are you able to access admin controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this reference [blog](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-admin-url.html). This may help you.